# Работа с ComboBox в потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте!
При попытке установить ValueMember для ComboBox в потоке получаю следующую ошибку:

> Этот компонент BackgroundWorker занят и не может одновременно выполнять несколько задач.

Код таков:

```
this.Invoke((Action) delegate
{
    metroComboBox1.DataSource = st;
    metroComboBox1.ValueMember = "name";
    metroComboBox1.DisplayMember = "id";
});
```

Спасибо!

Comment: @Bulson, как это должно помочь?

Comment: @Bulson, а что в этом вопросе ему противоречит?